# How to install win32gui on anaconda on macOS

Tags: python, win32gui

I am getting the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32gui''. Please brief me the instructions on how can I resolve this issue on my anaconda on mac.

Comment: How do you plan to use `win32gui` on a Mac? It’s quite literally meant for automating GUIs of *Windows* applications in an *Windows* environment.

Comment: I am working on Handwritten Digit Recognition project. 
I am using the following code: https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-deep-learning-project-handwritten-digit-recognition/
Everything worked fine before the GUI part. I want to make the GUI for the same. Please can you provide me with the code.

Comment: Or can you correct the code which can work on my mac

Comment: Through wine you could run it maybe somehow, but it is weird what you're doing, you should use PyQT.

Answer (score -1):

You must install it from the version hosted on the [pip package manager](https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/). You can do this with the following command:

```
pip install win32gui
```

Comment: This is not working. It is giving the following errors:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32gui (from versions: 221.3, 221.4, 221.5)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32gui
And So on....